# Starting with ui.bootstrap - parse error from angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just started to use ui-bootstrap module.

Here is my code, I think, I have imported everything right, no ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
    <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>

<script>

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

    mainApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.alerts = [
        { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
        { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
      ];

      $scope.addAlert = function() {
        $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
      };

      $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
      };

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have this error, when I click on Add Alert :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$parse/syntax?p0=alert.type&p1=is%20unex…20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Balert.type%7D%7D&p4=alert.type%7D%7D
```

do you have any ideas, why ?

futhermore, alert div are not displayed, maybe I cannot display the template from ui-bootstrap ?

EDIT :

We should use this `type="alert.type"` rather than  `type="{{alert.type}}"`

Comment: You have no `ng-app` in the HTML

Comment: There is one in the "html" marked.

Comment: The URL in the error message should give a pointer... https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=alert.type&p1=is%20unex%E2%80%A620expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Balert.type%7D%7D&p4=alert.type%7D%7D You don't use `{{}}` inside tags. Remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if its in your orginal code but in line:

```
mainApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {s
```

you have "s" on the end of line.

Comment: Just edited my post. It was not in my code... still not working.

Comment: in line `$scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});` you do not have a type property.

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhPVLyJMuDrDqhTvA8wz?p=preview)
here you have working example of your code. Diffrences is that i loaded libraries from external source. Check if your version of libraries are the same.

Comment: ok I have a problem with semi-colons because I am not using an external source ? I chose the newer version.

Comment: This example [plunker click](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) is from UI bootstrap. As you can se in demo they use angular v 1.2.10 and Ui bootstrap v 0.11.0. I insert your code and add the same resources with correct version and it working good [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhPVLyJMuDrDqhTvA8wz?p=preview). So i think you must use diffrent version of angular or UI bootstrap